# Is there a 'good' way to enable a user to use wg-quick without root access?

Tags: permissions, root

I've set up wireguard and I am very happy with it, I can't help but wonder two things though:

1. How come wg-quick can only be used by root ?
2. Can I give another user permission to do `wg-quick <up/down> <interface>` without actual root access?

I am guessing that it was to do with moving/copying/symlinking the file into a root owned directory, and reloading a daemon or something. Anyhow, I'd love some elaboration and a suggestion to a solution

Comment: If you have NetworkManager, you can make it so `nmcli` can bring it up and down https://blogs.gnome.org/thaller/2019/03/15/wireguard-in-networkmanager/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning: Following this answer is a security risk, It gives full root access with no password needed, to the user.**

Using hint from @ctrl-alt-delor answer, I managed to craft a working solution.
In my scenario, I wanted a non sudo user called jenkins being able to run wg-quick <up/down>  just like author.

Run:  `sudo visudo`

```
root            ALL = (ALL) ALL
%admin          ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

Below added lines -------

```
jenkins ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/homebrew/bin/bash
jenkins ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/networksetup
jenkins ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifconfig
jenkins ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/homebrew/bin/wg
jenkins ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/homebrew/bin/wg-quick
```

It's important to list the prerequisites before the final command that we want to execute! Otherwise, it will not work! I hope that this will help someone!

After this, the normal user jenkins was able to run this command.
If you face

```
encountered an error: "wg-quick: Version mismatch: bash 3 detected, when bash 4+ required"
```

then simply run

```
which bash
```

copy path output and put it at the beggining of wg-quick file(`/opt/homebrew/bin/wg-quick`)

In my case, top of the wg-quick will have: `#!/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`

After this operation, user can run this wg-quick up/down and execute this job from automator/sh script :)

Resource used:
https://osxdaily.com/2014/02/06/add-user-sudoers-file-mac/

Comment: As one of the other answers noted, you have just given the 'jenkins' user unrestricted root access, by allowing them to run a root-level shell. Working with system-level commands in sudo is generally going to open up a number of security issues, unless you are *very* strict in your command definitions, which - at some point - will be more work than it's worth. Please consider the implications of your sudoers rules very carefully.

Comment: You may as well add `jenkins` to group `admin`, with no password needed. This configuration gives god access to everything.

Answer (score 3):

wg-quick requires root access because it's using wg and ip to make changes to network interfaces.

Do not add wg-quick to sudoers, it will give unrestricted root access. wg-quick configs have hooks to run arbitrary scripts (PreUp, PostUp, etc.) as root, "most commonly used to configure custom DNS options or firewall rules."

wg-quick is really a convenience script as the manpage says:

> Generally speaking, this utility is just a simple script that wraps
>   invocations to wg(8) and ip(8) in order to set up a WireGuard
>   interface. It is designed for users with simple needs, and users with
>   more advanced needs are highly encouraged to use a more specific tool,
>   a more complete network manager, or otherwise just use wg(8) and ip(8),
>   as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. **But don't (see other answers).**

**Warning: don't do this for this command.**

## Option 1: Figure out why, and do the right thing.

## Option 2: `sudo`

Run with `sudo` and type password. I guess that you are already doing this.

## Option 3: configure password-less `sudo` for this command.

**Un-safe for this command.**

Edit the `/etc/sudoers` file, so that you can run **this command** with `sudo` and no password. (Be careful, use visudo to validate the file.)

When this is working, you can write a wrapper script, to make it easier to run.

Comment: How to edit such file? I have a regular user and admin user accounts. I would like to edit it in a way such regular user can execute wg-quick withoud need for sudo or password. Help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: @pawisoon read `man sudoers`. Configure so that command can be run with `sudo`, but no password needed. Then write a script wrapper, shell-function or alias, to make the `sudo` invisible.

Answer (score 0):

On my own laptop, just solved this by applying suid bit to `wg-quick` and `wg` executable.

```
which wg: /usr/bin/wg
which wg-quick: /usr/bin/wg-quick

sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/wg-quick
sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/wg
```

Comment: This enables any user to execute any arbitrary code as root. For example: `echo -e "[Interface]\nPreUp = whoami" > /tmp/exploit.conf && wg-quick up /tmp/exploit.conf`